# Changing css property of elements having similar kind of id's

Tags: php, javascript

I am having a problem while changing the css property of elements having similar kind if id's using javascript.

I am running a php loop through a series of hidden elements. So I am having there id's like this `imgstat_1`, `imgstat_2` and so on.

The code i am using is

```
foreach($img as $img1){?>
    <li>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeimgstat('<?php echo $counter;?>')">
         <img src="<?php echo $img1->vchEventImg?>" width="75" height="75" alt="" id="abc_<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>" />
       </a>
    </li>
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>" id="imgstat_<?php echo $counter;?>">
    <?php $counter++;
}?>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="newimg" id="newimg">
```

and javascript like this

```
function changeimgstat(obj)
{
     var xyz = document.getElementById('newimg').value;
     alert(document.getElementById('abc_'+xyz));
     document.getElementById('abc_'+obj).style.border="3px solid red";
     var status = document.getElementById('imgstat_'+obj).value;
     document.getElementById('newimg').value = status;
}
```

So could someone suggest what i am doing wrong

Comment: You might start with valid HTML. An input element can't be a sibling of an li element. Also, post the actual HTML that your page gets, not PHP since we don't know what things like `imgstat_<?php echo $counter;?>` generate.

Comment: When i alert as above i get null in the alert box RobG

Comment: Try this in `script` = `alert(document.getElementById('abc_'+obj));`, as you didn't assign a `value` in `hidden field whose id is newimg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found there is no error in your code, but have you defined `$counter` before `foreach loop`. And your `img id` should be `abc_<?php echo $counter?>` rather than `abc_<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>` which you are using in `javascript`.

Try:

**CSS**

```
.img3{border:3px solid red;}
.img{border:none;}
```

**HTML and PHP**

```
<?php
$counter=1;
foreach($img as $img1){?>
    <li>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeimgstat('<?php echo $counter;?>')">
         <img class="img" src="<?php echo $img1->vchEventImg?>" width="75" height="75" alt=""  id="abc_<?php echo $counter?>" />
       </a>
    </li>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>" id="imgstat_<?php echo $counter;?>">
    <?php $counter++;
}?>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="newimg" id="newimg">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
function removeAllClass()
{
    var allimg=document.getElementsByClassName("img");
    for(var index=0;index<allimg.length;index++)
    {
        allimg[index].className = "img";
    }
}   

function changeimgstat(obj)
{
     removeAllClass();
     document.getElementById('abc_'+obj).className="img img3";
     var status = document.getElementById('imgstat_'+obj).value;
     document.getElementById('newimg').value = status;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can apply `common class` on `images` like `img`, so that you can use for removing `class = img3` which is applied `previously`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to add a css class attribute to elements. And write styles for the class.

In the onclick function you can add the class to the elements

Comment: but i have to remove class as well from previous element

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have:

```
<img ... id="abc_<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>">
```

and

```
<input ... value="<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>" id="imgstat_<?php echo $counter;?>">
```

Are you sure these two elements will have the id you expect?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
foreach($img as $img1){?>
    <li>
       <a href="#" onclick="changeimgstat('<?php echo $counter;?>')">
         <img src="<?php echo $img1->vchEventImg?>" width="75" height="75" alt="" id="abc_<?php echo $counter;?>" />
       </a>
    </li>
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $img1->vchImgStatus?>" id="imgstat_<?php echo $counter;?>">
    <?php $counter++;
}?>
<input type="hidden" value="" name="newimg" id="newimg">
```

Javascript:

```
function changeimgstat(obj)
{
     var xyz = document.getElementById('newimg').value;
     alert(document.getElementById('abc_'+xyz));
     document.getElementById('abc_'+obj).style.border="3px solid red";
     var status = document.getElementById('imgstat_'+obj).value;
     document.getElementById('newimg').value = status;
}
```

I have changes the id="abc_"
because in the javascript function the parameter passed by you is the counter so the same shoul be the id value.

Comment: In that case I have to remove class to one element and remove class from another

Comment: i dont think you would need to do that. the class can be used to change the style and the id you were using for the status value (imgstat) will do its part

Comment: I tried this but its not removing the class from previous clicked element